Deleted Process (CacheDelete)
There is a reoccurring error every time I start my Macbook where the deleted process takes up a significant amount of my CPU. I've attached a log below. In Console.app I searched for the problem and have thousands of these below

Date/Time:        2024-07-13 07:23:01.572 +0200
End time:         2024-07-13 07:25:24.477 +0200
OS Version:       macOS 14.5 (Build 23F79)
Architecture:     x86_64h
Report Version:   49
Incident Identifier: CCCCB136-30DF-4367-9E90-851A0BC84C7B

Data Source:      Microstackshots
Shared Cache:     B48CFC6B-B7ED-3343-97FB-F5187DC04DF8 slid base address 0x7ff80cea0000, slide 0xcea0000

Command:          deleted
Path:             /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/deleted
Codesigning ID:   com.apple.deleted
Resource Coalition ID: 492
Architecture:     x86_64
Parent:           UNKNOWN [1]
PID:              465

Event:            cpu usage
Action taken:     none
CPU:              90 seconds cpu time over 143 seconds (63% cpu average), exceeding limit of 50% cpu over 180 seconds
CPU limit:        90s
Limit duration:   180s
CPU used:         90s
CPU duration:     143s
Duration:         142.90s
Duration Sampled: 121.79s
Steps:            40

Hardware model:   MacBookPro16,2
Active cpus:      8
HW page size:     4096
VM page size:     4096

Time Since Boot:  596s
Time Awake Since Boot: 596s
Time Since Wake:  n/a (machine hasn't slept)

Fan speed:        3015 rpm
Total CPU Time:   77.059s
Advisory levels:  Battery -> 3, User -> 2, ThermalPressure -> 0, Combined -> 2
Free disk space:  272.55 GB/465.63 GB, low space threshold 3072 MB
Vnodes Available: 88.83% (233774/263168, 81633 allocated)

Preferred User Language: en, en-JP
Keyboards:        ABC
OS Cryptex File Extents: 10

Heaviest stack for the target process:
  29  start_wqthread + 15 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 6863) [0x7ff80d2d7acf]
  29  _pthread_wqthread + 327 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 11140) [0x7ff80d2d8b84]
  29  _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 451 (libdispatch.dylib + 77098) [0x7ff80d14ad2a]
  29  _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 271 (libdispatch.dylib + 78868) [0x7ff80d14b414]
  29  _dispatch_lane_invoke + 377 (libdispatch.dylib + 39319) [0x7ff80d141997]
  29  _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 387 (libdispatch.dylib + 36194) [0x7ff80d140d62]
  29  _dispatch_lane_invoke + 377 (libdispatch.dylib + 39319) [0x7ff80d141997]
  29  _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 800 (libdispatch.dylib + 36607) [0x7ff80d140eff]
  29  _dispatch_client_callout + 8 (libdispatch.dylib + 11708) [0x7ff80d13adbc]
  29  _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12 (libdispatch.dylib + 6854) [0x7ff80d139ac6]
  29  __46-[CDService servicePurgeable:info:replyBlock:]_block_invoke.93 + 125 (deleted + 272957) [0x1062e8a3d]
  29  -[AppContainerCaches _servicePurgeable:info:replyBlock:] + 525 (deleted + 326095) [0x1062f59cf]
  29  -[AppContainerCaches processContainerCachesForVolume:bytesNeeded:urgency:calculate:verbose:telemetry:] + 135 (deleted + 322531) [0x1062f4be3]
  29  -[AppContainerCaches cachesForInstalledApps:volume:sortForUrgency:telemetry:] + 344 (deleted + 318279) [0x1062f3b47]
  29  +[AppCache enumerateAppCachesOnVolume:telemetry:block:] + 120 (CacheDelete + 223934) [0x7ff81e9d8abe]
  29  +[AppCache enumerateWithContainerQuery:container_class:telemetry:block:] + 344 (CacheDelete + 220325) [0x7ff81e9d7ca5]
  29  ??? (libsystem_containermanager.dylib + 73238) [0x7ff817885e16]
  29  __72+[AppCache enumerateWithContainerQuery:container_class:telemetry:block:]_block_invoke + 2093 (CacheDelete + 222827) [0x7ff81e9d866b]
  29  +[AppCache appCacheWithRecords:identifier:dataContainerURL:personaUniqueString:isDataseparated:isPlaceholder:isPlugin:telemetry:] + 570 (CacheDelete + 211356) [0x7ff81e9d599c]
  29  -[AppCache initWithBundleRecords:identifier:dataContainerURL:personaUniqueString:isDataseparated:isPlaceholder:isPlugin:telemetry:] + 589 (CacheDelete + 210243) [0x7ff81e9d5543]
  29  -[AppCache tmp:purge:all:] + 167 (CacheDelete + 215038) [0x7ff81e9d67fe]
  26  traverse_dir_with_state + 452 (CacheDelete + 154008) [0x7ff81e9c7998]
  10  clearPointerAt + 0 (Foundation + 178346) [0x7ff80e3378aa]


Powerstats for:   deleted [465]
UUID:             3251F1B7-DB6C-3211-8B29-FDA8762099A0
Path:             /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/deleted
Codesigning ID:   com.apple.deleted
Resource Coalition ID: 492
Architecture:     x86_64
Parent:           UNKNOWN [1]
UID:              501
Sudden Term:      Tracked (allows idle exit)
Footprint:        145.30 MB
Start time:       2024-07-13 07:23:47.457 +0200
End time:         2024-07-13 07:25:22.160 +0200
Num samples:      29 (72%)
Num threads:      1
Primary state:    24 samples Non-Frontmost App, Non-Suppressed, User mode, Effective Thread QoS Background, Requested Thread QoS Utility, Override Thread QoS Unspecified
User Activity:    29 samples Idle, 0 samples Active
Power Source:     0 samples on Battery, 29 samples on AC
  29  start_wqthread + 15 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 6863) [0x7ff80d2d7acf]
    29  _pthread_wqthread + 327 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 11140) [0x7ff80d2d8b84]
      29  _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 451 (libdispatch.dylib + 77098) [0x7ff80d14ad2a]
        29  _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 271 (libdispatch.dylib + 78868) [0x7ff80d14b414]
          29  _dispatch_lane_invoke + 377 (libdispatch.dylib + 39319) [0x7ff80d141997]
            29  _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 387 (libdispatch.dylib + 36194) [0x7ff80d140d62]
              29  _dispatch_lane_invoke + 377 (libdispatch.dylib + 39319) [0x7ff80d141997]
                29  _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 800 (libdispatch.dylib + 36607) [0x7ff80d140eff]
                  29  _dispatch_client_callout + 8 (libdispatch.dylib + 11708) [0x7ff80d13adbc]
                    29  _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12 (libdispatch.dylib + 6854) [0x7ff80d139ac6]
                      29  __46-[CDService servicePurgeable:info:replyBlock:]_block_invoke.93 + 125 (deleted + 272957) [0x1062e8a3d]
                        29  -[AppContainerCaches _servicePurgeable:info:replyBlock:] + 525 (deleted + 326095) [0x1062f59cf]
                          29  -[AppContainerCaches processContainerCachesForVolume:bytesNeeded:urgency:calculate:verbose:telemetry:] + 135 (deleted + 322531) [0x1062f4be3]
                            29  -[AppContainerCaches cachesForInstalledApps:volume:sortForUrgency:telemetry:] + 344 (deleted + 318279) [0x1062f3b47]
                              29  +[AppCache enumerateAppCachesOnVolume:telemetry:block:] + 120 (CacheDelete + 223934) [0x7ff81e9d8abe]
                                29  +[AppCache enumerateWithContainerQuery:container_class:telemetry:block:] + 344 (CacheDelete + 220325) [0x7ff81e9d7ca5]
                                  29  ??? (libsystem_containermanager.dylib + 73238) [0x7ff817885e16]
                                    29  __72+[AppCache enumerateWithContainerQuery:container_class:telemetry:block:]_block_invoke + 2093 (CacheDelete + 222827) [0x7ff81e9d866b]
                                      29  +[AppCache appCacheWithRecords:identifier:dataContainerURL:personaUniqueString:isDataseparated:isPlaceholder:isPlugin:telemetry:] + 570 (CacheDelete + 211356) [0x7ff81e9d599c]
                                        29  -[AppCache initWithBundleRecords:identifier:dataContainerURL:personaUniqueString:isDataseparated:isPlaceholder:isPlugin:telemetry:] + 589 (CacheDelete + 210243) [0x7ff81e9d5543]
                                          29  -[AppCache tmp:purge:all:] + 167 (CacheDelete + 215038) [0x7ff81e9d67fe]
                                            26  traverse_dir_with_state + 452 (CacheDelete + 154008) [0x7ff81e9c7998]
                                              10  clearPointerAt + 0 (Foundation + 178346) [0x7ff80e3378aa]
                                                1   <Kernel mode>
                                              3   clearPointerAt + 12 (Foundation + 178358) [0x7ff80e3378b6]
                                              2   -[NSConcretePointerArray removePointerAtIndex:] + 212 (Foundation + 196660) [0x7ff80e33c034]
                                                2   clearPointerAt + 11 (Foundation + 178357) [0x7ff80e3378b5]
                                              2   -[NSConcretePointerArray removePointerAtIndex:] + 197 (Foundation + 196645) [0x7ff80e33c025]
                                              2   -[NSConcretePointerArray removePointerAtIndex:] + 152 (Foundation + 196600) [0x7ff80e33bff8]
                                              2   readPointerAt + 0 (Foundation + 76950) [0x7ff80e31ec96]
                                              1   -[NSConcretePointerArray removePointerAtIndex:] + 234 (Foundation + 196682) [0x7ff80e33c04a]
                                                1   <Kernel mode>
                                              1   -[NSConcretePointerArray removePointerAtIndex:] + 186 (Foundation + 196634) [0x7ff80e33c01a]
                                                1   storePointerAt + 8 (Foundation + 27699) [0x7ff80e312c33]
                                              1   -[NSConcretePointerArray removePointerAtIndex:] + 177 (Foundation + 196625) [0x7ff80e33c011]
                                              1   storePointerAt + 9 (Foundation + 27700) [0x7ff80e312c34]
                                              1   storePointerAt + 0 (Foundation + 27691) [0x7ff80e312c2b]
                                            3   getattrlistbulk + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 16202) [0x7ff80d29ef4a]
                                              3   <Kernel mode>

  Binary Images:
           0x1062a6000 -        0x106319fff  deleted (660.120.3.0.1)                      <3251F1B7-DB6C-3211-8B29-FDA8762099A0>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/deleted
        0x7ff80d138000 -     0x7ff80d17eff1  libdispatch.dylib (1477.100.9)               <511B909B-7A60-3295-9981-A508477C7893>  /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
        0x7ff80d29b000 -     0x7ff80d2d5ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (10063.121.3)         <13597EEB-2EA0-3D48-8BE1-DFC4872A784B>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
        0x7ff80d2d6000 -     0x7ff80d2e1ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (519.120.4)          <25B2F3EB-07B4-3CB9-9457-2C26210C27C8>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
        0x7ff80e30c000 -     0x7ff80ef42ff3  com.apple.Foundation 6.9 (2503.1)            <086A9E16-7C3A-32B4-821E-214A25C9A7EB>  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
        0x7ff817874000 -     0x7ff81789cffb  libsystem_containermanager.dylib (582.120.2) <EF5C55A8-AEFF-3AE7-8365-42FA0CA0C9A9>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
        0x7ff81e9a2000 -     0x7ff81e9efffb  com.apple.CacheDelete 1.0 (1)                <8C0ACC23-9CBB-3A0E-B728-8AD4D8D4ACE0>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/Versions/A/CacheDelete


Powerstats for:   Camera Hub
UUID:             1D6FBC35-6301-3B53-B475-D14D534AA06C
Path:             /Applications/Elgato Camera Hub.app/Contents/MacOS/Camera Hub
Identifier:       com.elgato.CameraHub
Version:          1.7.0 (1124)
Team ID:          Y93VXCB8Q5
Is First Party:   No
Beta Identifier:  836C4D6C-40A3-563D-A8B4-2D7B189DD623
Resource Coalition ID: 522
Architecture:     x86_64
Start time:       2024-07-13 07:25:06.056 +0200
End time:         2024-07-13 07:25:24.176 +0200
Num samples:      5 (12%)
Primary state:    5 samples Non-Frontmost App, Non-Suppressed, Kernel mode, Effective Thread QoS Utility, Requested Thread QoS Default, Override Thread QoS Unspecified
User Activity:    5 samples Idle, 0 samples Active
Power Source:     0 samples on Battery, 5 samples on AC
  5  thread_start + 15 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 6883) [0x7ff80d2d7ae3]
    5  _pthread_start + 99 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 24971) [0x7ff80d2dc18b]
      4  ??? (Camera Hub + 4651789) [0x109613b0d]
        4  ??? (Camera Hub + 4650757) [0x109613705]
          4  std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l>>>) + 93 (libc++.1.dylib + 48539) [0x7ff80d215d9b]
            4  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 16250) [0x7ff80d29ef7a]
      1  CAnyThreadRunner::ThreadEntry(void*) + 32 (Camera Hub + 7629024) [0x1098ea8e0]
        1  ??? (Camera Hub + 6856527) [0x10982df4f]
          1  ??? (Camera Hub + 6853894) [0x10982d506]
            1  ??? (Camera Hub + 9882467) [0x109b10b63]
              1  ??? (Camera Hub + 6845092) [0x10982b2a4]
                1  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 16250) [0x7ff80d29ef7a]

  Binary Images:
           0x1091a4000 -        0x10a923fff  com.elgato.CameraHub 1.7.0 (1124)    <1D6FBC35-6301-3B53-B475-D14D534AA06C>  /Applications/Elgato Camera Hub.app/Contents/MacOS/Camera Hub
        0x7ff80d20a000 -     0x7ff80d284ff3  libc++.1.dylib (1700.255.5)          <E443AF07-488B-3B1B-83AE-31BD883E6EF1>  /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
        0x7ff80d29b000 -     0x7ff80d2d5ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (10063.121.3) <13597EEB-2EA0-3D48-8BE1-DFC4872A784B>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
        0x7ff80d2d6000 -     0x7ff80d2e1ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (519.120.4)  <25B2F3EB-07B4-3CB9-9457-2C26210C27C8>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib



I ended up being able to solve this after performing several processes. Restarted in recovery (CMD+R) and ran terminal to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) using csrutil disable.
Then, I restarted and ran the following through the terminal
sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/*
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Caches/*
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/*
Restarted in recovery a second time and ran csrutil enable.
I had previously tried to take ownership as a root user of the files, but the action was not successful without disabling SIP. I'm not sure why this action happened. Rebuilt mds and it seems all is solved now. No DeleteCache at all 0%.
